# strtok cause core dump

Tags: c, pointers, coredump

I run this code and core dumped...

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *a= "ls";
    char *b= "ls -l";
    char *t = strtok(b," \t");
    if (!strcmp(a,t))
        printf("EQU\n");
    else
        printf("NOT EQU\n");
}
```

But after I change `char *b="ls -l";` to `char b[]="ls -l"`, it works.

Why?

I know that One is an array, and the other is a pointer. But are they different for strtok? 
And the manual page for strtok says that the first argument should be a char*.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`man page`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), `strtok` modifies its first element.

When you initialize a `char*` with a literal string, you are pointing into the read-only memory that the literal was allocated in.

When you initialize a `char[]` with a literal string, it gets its own private memory, which is writeable.

Thus, you core dump on the first one but not the second one.

Answer (score 1):

`strtok` modifies the input string. It overwrites instances of the delimiter characters with null bytes in order to split the string up into null-terminated strings for each token. String literals are compiled into the program and typically reside in read-only segments of memory. As such, they can't be modified, and attempting to do so will result in a crash.

You could just modify your code to store the string on the stack as you've done:

```
char b[] = "ls -l";
```

Or create a temporary copy of the string:

```
char *str = strdup(b);
free(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual if the function `char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );`:

> `str`
>
> C string to truncate.
>
> Notice that **this string is modified** by being broken into smaller strings (tokens).
>
> Alternativelly, a null pointer may be specified, in which case the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ended.

It tries to modify the const string literal `char *b= "ls -l";` that is located in the read only memory and the program core dumped. When you modify the variable declaration to `char b[]= "ls -l";`, the string is located on the stack of `main`, data on stack can be modified.